# Partial and Total Derivative Double check

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I haven’t done these in about 15 years, did a little googling and feel confident, but want to make sure

First and second order partial derivatives (including cross partials)

If   $F(x,y)=3x^2+3xy-4x^{-1}y^2$

$F_x(x,y)=6x+3y+4x^{-2}y^2$

$F_{xx}(x,y)=6-8x^{-3}y^2$

Cross partial
$F_{xy}(x,y)$ and be $2+8x^{-2}y$

Then just do the same but flipping order of integration for the rest?

Total derivative I take the respected derivative and add them together?

$F(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$

$F_x(x,y)=(2x+y) $

$F_y(x,y)=(x+2y) $

Total derivative is $(2x+y)dx + (x+2y)dy$

Are these all correct?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to ask questions, it is kinda hard to read otherwise: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the first half, $F_{xy}(x,y) = 3+8x^{-2}y^2$ ... but you clearly know what you were doing, so we can chalk that up to a typo.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to go back and double check, but must have missed that in my sloppy work on paper

Everything else look good though?

Thanks